# How can I get rid of distracting mess of lines from a vertex group?

Tags: vertex-groups

Howcome I get a bunch of unnecessary lines forming a massive ball of yarn around my doughnut?  Related to the icing, sprinkles and vertex group and disappears when I switch off overlays.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I unchecked Object_Extras and it disappeared.  Some empty wire or visual guide.  Not sure what purpose it served but I guess I will find out later when I delve deeper into Blender.